# ¿Cómo agregar elementos a un objeto en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

espero me puedan ayudar, digamos que tengo el siguiente código:

```
 let estudiantes = {
    nombres: ["Alfredo Velazquez", "Marisol Romero"],
    edades: {
        0: 18,
        1: 17
    },
    direcciones: {
        0: "C. Carranza #3",
        1: "C. Tepic #2",
    },
};
```

si quisiera agregar por ejemplo, un nuevo nombre a la propiedad de nombres intentaba de esta manera, pero no me sale:

```
estudiantes["nombres"] = {
        0: "Alfredo Velazquez", 
        1: "Marisol Romero",
        2: "Javier Sosa"
      }
```

espero me puedan ayudar, no necesariamente con la respuésta, pero con una pista al menos.
gracias

Comment: nombres es un array, no un objeto, investiga sobre `push()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar un elemento a la lista de la propiedad "nombres" se hace mediante un push.

```js
 let estudiantes = {
    nombres: ["Alfredo Velazquez", "Marisol Romero"],
    edades: {
        0: 18,
        1: 17
    },
    direcciones: {
        0: "C. Carranza #3",
        1: "C. Tepic #2",
    },
};
estudiantes["nombres"].push("Javier Sosa");
console.log("Result:",estudiantes);
```